# Assembly recognized at design but not compile time in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to use a component I downloaded from code project ([here's](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/menus/NaviPane.aspx) the link). I'm trying to add it to my project by adding a reference to all 3 assemblies (dll's). I can see the components on design time. I can add them to my form but I get "The type or namespace name ..." errors when I try to run it. I tried rebuilding and cleaning solution but I still get the same problem. Any idea what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set them to be copied to the output directory? If the dll's are just referenced in your project but are not in the directory (or under it) that you are running from then at runtime they will not be found and thus give you the error you are seeing.

Comment: Okay, that is always one I check first.